# Vue.js - Calling an asynchronous method inline

Tags: javascript, vue.js, axios

I would like to use a method to make an API call in a v-for loop, the purpose is to load an object based on a UID.

My method looks like this:

```
methods: {
  async getTodo(uid) {
  const data = await axios.get(
    "https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos/" + uid
  );
  return data;
}
```

}

From my understanding you can include methods inline as such:

```
{{ getTodo(2) }}
```

However this always returns [object Promise]

I must have misunderstand the use of methods for this purpose, or the async call in the method itself is incorrect — if anyone can clarify what is wrong here.

Comment: Its a promise - pass value to data instead return

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can store the asynchronous response in a reactive array when the promise returns. Since it's reactive, the promise response will automatically be displayed once each promise return.

Do something like:

```
export default {
  data: {
    asyncDataHolder: []
  },
  methods: {
    async getTodo(uid) {
    const data = await axios.get(
      "https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos/" + uid
    );
    let index = asyncDataHolder.length + 1;
    asyncDataHolder.$set(index, data);
}
```

And inside your `v-for` loop:

```
{{asyncDataHolder[i]}}
```

Comment: I would never say _The ideal logic to do such a thing_. There are plenty of other solutions pretty clean to obtain this result. Moreover, the given solution has huge drawback: if the user stays long enough on this page, it will explode memory since your `index` has no link with `uid`. You could at least store your data within an object rather than an array. Another drawback is that you never _call_ the `getTodo` method. I'd do this within the `mounted` hook.

Comment: Ok, you're right. I've updated the answer. About the `mounted hook`, it's not clear to methe entire flow... That's why I've focused in just giving him an option that works. Upvote for your note.